# Código C - No me sale el numero en este Código de Búsqueda Binaria

Tags: c, busqueda-binaria

*Buenas,*

*Estuve realizando un programa en el lenguaje de C de Búsqueda Binaria, que utiliza un arreglo de números enteros que contiene los siguientes valores: 10, 17, 6, 33, 5, 21, 42, 8, 3, 22, 15, 13, 1, 55, 50, 9, 18, 7, 25, 2; con la finalidad de que busque los siguientes elementos: 15, 20, 10.*

*Sin embargo, no me aparece el resultado de la posición de los números que busco.*

*Codigo:*

```
#include<stdio.h>

int busquedaBinaria(int a[], int dato, int inicio, int fin);

int main()
{
int a[] = {10, 17, 6, 33, 5, 21, 42, 8, 3, 22, 15, 13, 1, 55, 50, 9, 18, 7, 25, 2};
int tam = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

int pos = busquedaBinaria(a,10,0,tam-1);
/*                           ^
                             |
           Aqui pongo el numero que deseo buscar*/


if(pos != -1){
    printf("El dato se encuentra en la posicion %d \n",pos);
}else{
    printf("El dato no se encuentra en el arreglo\n");
}

return 0;
}

int busquedaBinaria(int a[], int dato, int inicio, int fin){
int mid;

while(inicio <= fin){
    mid = (inicio + fin) / 2;
    if(a[mid] == dato){
        return mid+1;
    }else if(dato < a[mid]){
        fin = mid -1;
    }else{
        inicio = mid + 1;
    }
}
return -1;

}
```

[image: Aunque el 10 se encuentre dentro del arreglo, el código no lo detecta y lo marca como si no existiera, al igual que la mayoría de los números dentro del arreglo.]

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: Cito a Wikipedia "En ciencias de la computación y matemáticas, la búsqueda binaria, también conocida, como búsqueda de intervalo medio1​ o búsqueda logarítmica,2​ es un algoritmo de búsqueda que encuentra la posición de un valor en un ***array ordenado***"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La cause del problema es que la búsqueda binaria exige que los datos estén ordenados. Ese es el único cambio necesario:

#### Demo

Además de ordenar el arreglo `a`, probe la búsqueda con todos los valores entre 1 y 56.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int busquedaBinaria(int a[], int dato, int inicio, int fin);

int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 15, 17, 18, 21, 22, 25, 33, 42, 50, 55};
    int tam = sizeof (a) / sizeof (a[0]);

    for (int dato=1; dato < 56; dato++) {
        int pos = busquedaBinaria(a, dato, 0, tam - 1);

        if (pos != -1) {
            printf("El dato %d se encuentra en la posicion %d \n", dato, pos);
        } else {
            printf("El dato %d no se encuentra en el arreglo\n", dato);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int busquedaBinaria(int a[], int dato, int inicio, int fin) {
    int mid;

    while (inicio <= fin) {
        mid = (inicio + fin) / 2;
        if (a[mid] == dato) {
            return mid + 1;
        } else if (dato < a[mid]) {
            fin = mid - 1;
        } else {
            inicio = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}
```

produce:

```
El dato 1 se encuentra en la posicion 1 
El dato 2 se encuentra en la posicion 2 
El dato 3 se encuentra en la posicion 3 
El dato 4 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 5 se encuentra en la posicion 4 
El dato 6 se encuentra en la posicion 5 
El dato 7 se encuentra en la posicion 6 
El dato 8 se encuentra en la posicion 7 
El dato 9 se encuentra en la posicion 8 
El dato 10 se encuentra en la posicion 9 
El dato 11 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 12 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 13 se encuentra en la posicion 10 
El dato 14 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 15 se encuentra en la posicion 11 
El dato 16 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 17 se encuentra en la posicion 12 
El dato 18 se encuentra en la posicion 13 
El dato 19 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 20 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 21 se encuentra en la posicion 14 
El dato 22 se encuentra en la posicion 15 
El dato 23 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 24 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 25 se encuentra en la posicion 16 
El dato 26 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 27 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 28 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 29 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 30 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 31 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 32 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 33 se encuentra en la posicion 17 
El dato 34 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 35 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 36 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 37 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 38 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 39 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 40 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 41 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 42 se encuentra en la posicion 18 
El dato 43 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 44 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 45 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 46 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 47 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 48 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 49 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 50 se encuentra en la posicion 19 
El dato 51 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 52 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 53 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 54 no se encuentra en el arreglo
El dato 55 se encuentra en la posicion 20     

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 0ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```